# Let $G$ be a cyclic group of order $n$. Then what can we say about n?

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

Let $G$ be a cyclic group of order $n$.  If $a$ and $a^2$ are both generators of $G$. Then what can we say about n?

There are three options:

- $3$ must be co-prime to $n$.
- $n$ is divisible by $3$.
- $3$ and $n$ may not prime integers.

I can show that the statement $2$ is incorrect.
But which is the correct answer then?
Please help me to solve this.

Comment: What does "3 and $n$ may not prime integers" mean?

Comment: "3 and $n$ may not _be_ prime integers."

Comment: Where did the number 3 come from?  We start with a cyclic group of unknown order $n$, and we know that $a$ and $a^2$ are both generators.  That means, $n$ is odd; otherwise, $a^2$ would fail to generate all of the group.

We also know that the group is abelian, since every cyclic group is, and also that it is isomorphic to ${\bf Z} / n {\bf Z}$; e.g., mapping $a$ to $1$ gives an isomorphism.

Anything else?

Comment: @SeanRoberson But 3 certainly is a prime integer. Do you mean relatively prime (aka. co-prime)? Then the third option is the same as the second

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I was trying to interpret the original post. Not sure if the OP meant relatively prime.

Comment: $\mathbb Z_3$ under addition, or $\{0, 1, 2\}$ is such $\langle 1\rangle = \langle 2\rangle = \{0, 1, 2\}.$  In this case the order of G is $n=3$, and so in this case, $n = 3$, hence certainly, n is divisible by 3. (option 2).

Answer (score 2):

In general, $a^2$ will generate a subgroup of index $2$ if $n$ is even and the whole group if $n$ is odd. Thus the correct answer is

4) $n$ is odd.

Comment: If a and a^3 are both the generators of G then what can we say about n?